# SSL/TLS errors using cURL (PHP) with a C# REST API and the SslStream class

Tags: c#, php, ssl, curl

I have written a REST API server in C#, it uses the `System.Net.Security.SslStream` class to provide SSL/TLS encryption.

I am also creating a web service which uses PHP + cURL to handle communication with the server.

Locally, I am using WAMP as a test environment, and all works fine.

However, upon uploading and testing on a remote environment, communication failed with the following error messages:

**cURL Error**

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to mywebsite.example:443
```

**SslStream Error**

`AuthenticationException` in `SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer()`:

```
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

Inner exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

This exception and error occurs when attempting to use TLS 1.2 authentication:

```
SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(ServerCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
```

I tried setting various cURL options such as:

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
```

but, alas, no joy.

After checking the `phpInfo()` configurations for differences, I noticed SSPI was enabled in the cURL settings locally, but not on the remote server:

[image: cURL settings]

I know very little about SSPI, in fact, mostly just what is summarised on Wikipedia:

> Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) is a Win32 API used by
>   Microsoft Windows systems to perform a variety of security-related
>   operations such as authentication.

So, it seems to make sense that this is the cause of the problem - but...

**I managed to achieve successful communication** by changing the `SslProtocols` type from `SslProtocols.Tls12` to just `SslProtocols.Tls`. However, from what I can tell, SSPI is not tied to any particular SSL protocol, so why did this work?

This is a workaround for now, but I would really like to understand the underlying issue causing this problem. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

I would much rather fully support TLS 1.2 and not have to downgrade.

Comment: Depending on which Windows version and the software running on it you may or may not have support for TLS 1.2. By using `SslProtocols.Tls` you are probably letting the client/server negotiate whatever version they can speak, and it could be TLS 1.0 or 1.1 but they have found a common ground, as it seems at least one party is not able to do TLS 1.2

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you, this is basically it. SSPI was a red-herring somewhat, instead I think I should have been looking at the 'Registered Stream Socket Transports' detail in phpInfo(). Only 'tls' is listed on the remote server, but locally there is 'tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2'. If you turn this in to an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not  related to SSPI in fact.

`SslProtocols.Tls` probably means: "auto-negotiate any suitable common version" while `SslProtocols.Tls12` means: "force TLS version 1.2"

So if you force TLS 1.2 but not all parties know this version, then the handshake will fail.
By letting them autonegotiate they are instead probably able to converge on TLS 1.1 or 1.0

Note that nowadays anything other than TLS 1.2 is not a good idea, or at least it should really be a temporary situation. Also TLS 1.3 just went out as a standard 2 weeks ago.

It is often better to let systems autonegotiate versions so that, when they are upgraded, they fall into the highest possible one at that time. So forcing `SslProtocols.Tls12` even if it had worked, would have been good in the short term (best TLS version right now) but not in long term (if both your systems were upgraded and capable of TLS 1.3 in some future, you would not profit from it which is sad as 1.3 is better than 1.2 in many aspects).

But, on the opposite, just letting them autonegotiate has some drawbacks:

1. while mostly cosmetic, the symbolic constant in OpenSSL to have this auto negotiation is very misleadingly called `SSLv23_METHOD` (where you have also `TLSv1_2_METHOD` for example) and this does **not** mean SSL 2 or SSL 3 (two things that should be now dead) but "whatever best we can autonegotiate" (on the generic issue of proper design and use of TLS APIs specifically outside the web, this is an eye-opening paper: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf)
2. more important, if you do not watch what is happening (logging), you could have systems autonegotiating very low versions like TLS 1.0 or even worse SSL 3.0 when you wanted at the same time something better. So you may have a running systems but not up to the security level you want or need.